# I Installed lamp-server but a tiny progrme of php not run

Tags: installation, php, lamp, html5

I have installed lamp in Ubuntu 12.04 using these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

and

```
$ sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

and run the following .php file in browser and it was executed by updating database

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","passwd","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35)");

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('Glenn', 'Quagmire',33)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But when I use a .html file to connect a .php file and update mysql database the .php does not execute and want to save in a folder (Download folder as default). 
The .html file is:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="/var/www/EnterName.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the EnterName.php file is:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","passwd","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Firstly, in order to help you we'll need to know *how* it isn't working - give us any error messages or unexpected actions.

Secondly, This is a question about programming, not Ubuntu; consider moving it to StackOverflow.

Comment: Is the file that actually executes the insert named `insert.php` or is it `EnterName.php`??

Comment: It is EnterName.php

Answer (score 0):

HTML form action value has to be public address. So if the html file and EnterName.php are in the same folder just use action="EnterName.php"

Comment: Yes, I have also tried that, keeping the html file at /var/www/ directory.